# horizontal scrolbar only appearing at bottom of page using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar

I am trying to make a page where data from a database is displayed, because I want to make it accessible on smaller devices where not all data fits on to the screen, so the user should be able to scroll from left to right. But the problem I am having now is that the scrollbar only appears when you are at the bottom of the page. [Picture when the page is at bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxD0y.png), [The page when i scroll even up a little](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlCnf.png). So what I want as a result is to have the scrollbar always there(except when the page is large enough to display all the data.)

I have tried the answer of this post: [Horizontal scrollbar only appearing at bottom of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200424/horizontal-scrollbar-only-appearing-at-bottom-of-page), but unfortunetly it did not work.

My code:

````
           <div class="container-fluid w100 h-100 mt-5">
                <div class="row">
                    <nav style="position: fixed; "class="col-md-2  pt-5 sidebar h-100 w100">
                     ....
                    </nav

                    <main role='main' style='background: white;' class='col-md-10 ml-auto col-lg-10 ';>
                    <h2 class='d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center 
                     pt-3 pb-2 mb-3'>Afspraken:</h2>
                    <div class='table-responsive'><table class='table table-sm table-striped'><thead 
                    align='left'><tr><th>Naam:</th><th>Reparatie</th><th>Telefoonnummer</th> 
                    <th>Email</th><th>Status</th><th>Datum</th><th>Datum</th></tr></thead><tbody>```
````

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you only enable the overflow-x on your table and the overflow-y on the body. My recommendation is, that you use overflow-y on your table and set a fixed height on your div with the class table-responsive.
Another option would be to add overflow-x to your body and display the whole width of the table on your body.

Comment: Ty for your comment, unfortunately it brings more problems then it solves. It screws over a lot of the responsiveness of the site for example when i shrink the height of the screen another vertical scrolbar comes up. I like the looks when at full screen though

Comment: @chielHoogma In that case, I would recommend having a look at this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934271/horizontal-scrollbar-on-top-and-bottom-of-table/22298769).
There is described how you can add a scrollbar at the top and at the bottom of the table. then you at least don't have to scroll all the way down the table.